# why "new"keyword is not used with getLayoutInflator();?

Tags: java, android, listview, layout-inflater

Why we dont write

```
LayoutInflator l = new getLayoutInflator();
```

Instead we write

```
LayoutInflator l = getLayoutInflator();
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a coding problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how its not a coding question can you please explain@dda

Comment: Because its a function call.

Comment: yes i know its a function call but to call function you need a object of a class Right?Even its not static method

Comment: When you are not writing any class instsnace to call a method, it is usually inside the extended class. You can ctrl + left click on the method if you are using AS to know see the actual code and where it is written.

Comment: It's unclear to me why this question has three close votes for "not a coding problem".

Answer (score 1):

You're calling an instance method, not constructing an object.

Within that method it makes a few `new` instances of things, then returns you a LayoutInflater

> but to call function you need a object of a class Right?

To *call a method*, you need an *instance of an object*, yes. You should learn about how `this` works in Java